# Who created the Tet?

Tags: oblivion

In Oblivion, the Tet arrived, destroyed the moon then made a cover up story that humans had fled to Titan, and it was itself a human launch pad.

But in reality the Tet was an autonomously functioning Artificial Intelligence which controlled the drones and killed humans.

My question is, who built the Tet? 
And could they send another one?

Comment: TET is a super AI, ascended far beyond its creator. In my opinion it has similar atributes to those Archailects of the Orions Arm universe

Comment: Maybe it was created by Xenu?

Answer (score 11):

**We aren't really meant to know who sent the Tet.** In the film, Beech explains that the Tet is another alien race that's seeking to take Earth's resources for itself. The Tet could be a sentient being all on its own, built by another race somewhere in the known universe that, after eliminating its creators, travels to other worlds, eradicates the dominant native species, and hoards the resources for itself.

Sometimes the scariest monsters are the ones we can imagine ourselves.

It's possible that whomever or whatever built the Tet could send another one, but they would really have to think about how they would do it. Humanity has shown they're fairly resilient, and managed to take down the Tet and reclaim their planet, and that alone may cause wherever the Tet came from the rethink doing it again.

Comment: *"Sometimes the scariest monsters are the ones we can imagine ourselves."* - Exactly. The *Tet* would be far less mysterious and engaging if we knew that it was just another scout drone from some standard alien race. The *Tet* is the *Tet* and that's really all we're *supposed* to know.

Comment: Which is saying a lot, because Oblivion is pretty thin on story. :P

Comment: Well, the overall story was maybe not thought-out that well in all details, but the story itself wasn't that uninteresting, I think, even if all the individual parts had be seen elsewhere already. And besides that, it definitely lived from its visual style, atmosphere and soundtrack, which, given that it wasn't a book but a movie, turned it into a pretty good experience for me.

Comment: Interesting, for some reason my immediate assumption was that the Tet wasn't 'sent' by anyone, that it was just a wandering entity, surviving by soaking up resources from one system then moving onto the next.  Though the Tet is an AI, it could have been the culmination of an ancient civilization and that it wasn't sent anymore than a wandering band of looters was 'sent' by someone.  It could even have even been 'sent away' since it's obviously not very empathetic or compassionate.

Answer (score 2):

The film seems to leave that possibility (another invasion) open as at no point does it ever address the true origins of the TET. However, what might be surmised from the scene near the end where 49 comes aboard the TET is that it believes itself to be an independent entity (it informs 49 that it is his "god").

Failing anything else apparent in the narrative it can be presumed that the TET is a sentient being whose creation was presumably by its own hands or by a race which no longer controls its actions.

Answer (score 0):

The Tet is an A.I super machine that originated somewhere in the universe by a highly advance alien race that has tegnology far beyond our own. Since the tet is a machice that thinks for itself, feeds and survives on the resourses of sustaining planets like earth, maybe the tet might have also fed of the planet of origin and killed of the race that brought it to existence. There also might be more machines like the tet in the universe

Comment: Can you provide sources for your claims?

Answer (score -1):

It seems the origin of the tet is only to be speculated, not to be explained fully. I would guess that it was created to gather resources when it was out of communicable range with its source. However it never returned (vger anyone?) And now sees earth. If it created itself then it wouldn't need biological entities to maintain itself or support itself. It would just create more machines from the vast resources it had accumulated. The cloning seems to be a prefabricated capability. Late I know.

Comment: This reads more like a comment than a fully realised answer, I'm afraid.

Answer (score -2):

The tet was created by an advanced alien race who had used up majority of the natural resources. They built the tet with super intelligence, and more than one. Its mission? To be fully self controlled, seek out alien world with resources, and bring the payload back home. But with this super intelligence, the tet became too self aware and instead of returning to her creators world, she simply just kept going, using the resourses she was designed to collect, for herself and own preservation. She has gone rogue, leaving her creators abandoned!. But her creators created more than one tet! They were scattered along 8 points of the galactic plane.

Answer (score -3):

The Tet was a humanity trial, humans had to prove that they were worth living.
The whole of humanity is sick and had to be removed, but there were some pure souls that hadn't forgotten how to use their minds for the good of all mankind, beyond their own desires.

A lot of great civilisations on Earth were whipped out and twisted like the Aztecs and Mayans, they have reached the top, and fall down morally.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've edited this to make it a little more coherent, but ultimately it doesn't answer the question. Consider either removing it or adding more details to it to specifically address *who created it and why*.

Comment: Fan-fiction is fun, but not a suitable answer.